# Filtering <iframe> src attribute

Tags: php, iframe, html-entities

I have a website that allows the user to embed their videos using `<iframe>` tags such as .

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/se2P7hjPanE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, this  is not a good idea since they can also input a website on src attribute and not a video. such as `<iframe src="http://www.google.com"/>`

Is there anyway to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the URLs submitted and filter them through a whitelist. Any that aren't on the list get either discarded or put in a queue for administrator approval.